# I updated to ubuntu 20.04 and now I can't type spaces in fish terminal

Tags: command-line, upgrade, fish

I just updated to ubuntu 20.04 and I use the fish terminal instead of bash. Now when I use fish I can't type a space anymore. Normally, on 19.10, I would type the start of a command and then space to autocomplete.

Example: [image: Example]

But since I updated to ubuntu 20.04 it seems that I can't type a space in the fish terminal anymore. The only way now is: Tab to autocomplete and then tab again for the space, but that doesn't always work and is annoying. Also, in my functions I have a few commands with spaces in them(mainly cd ~/) but the space from that command is also missing, so all my functions are failing.

Please can somebody help me with this problem?

Kind regards, Blub

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling Fish, there probably was something wrong in one of the config files deep down. I got it working now!